# About the composition of Linux command

Tags: linux, command, composition

Assuming:

1. the path of file f is ~/f
2. "which f" shows "~/f",

Then,

`which f | cat` shows `~/f`. So `cat` here is applied to the quotation of `~/f`, which is different with `cat ~/f`.

My question is: how I could use one command composed of `which` and `cat` to achieve the result of `cat ~/f`? When I don't know the result of `which f` in advance, using this composition can be very convenient. Currently, if I don't know the result of `which f` in advance, I have to invoke `which f` first, and copy-paste the result to feed `less`.

A related question is: how can I assign the result of `which f` to a variable?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` cat "`which f`" ``

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cat `which ~/f`
```

For the related question:

```
foo=`which ~/f`
echo $foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so in `bash`:

```
cat "$(which f)"
var="$(which f)"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
cat `which f`
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, you can use:

```
cat "$(which f)"
```

to output the contents of the `f` that `which` finds. This, like the backtick solution, takes the output of the command within `$(...)` and uses that as a parameter to the `cat` command.

I prefer the `$(...)` to the backtick method since the former can be nested in more complex situations.

Assigning the output of `which` to a variable is done similarly:

```
full_f="$(which f)"
```

In both cases, it's better to use the quotes in case `f`, or it's path, contains spaces, as heinous as that crime is :-)

I've often used a similar trick when I want to edit a small group of files with similar names under a given sub-directory:

```
vim $(find . -type f -name Makefile)
```

which will give me a single `vim` session for all the makefiles (obviously, if there were a large number, I'd be using `sed` or `perl` to modify them en masse instead of `vim`).

Answer (score 0):

In `which f | cat` the `cat` program gets the output of `which f` on standard input. That then just passes that standard input through, so the result is the same as a plain `which f`. In the call `cat ~/f` the data is passed as a parameter to the command. `cat` then opens the file `~/f` and displays it's contents.

To get the output of `which f` as a parameter to `cat` you can, as others have answered, use backticks or `$()`:

```
cat `which f`
cat $(which f)
```

Here the shell takes the output of `which f` and inserts it as a parameter for `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

`cat` echos the contents of files to the standard output. When you write `stuff | cat`, the file cat works on is the standard input, which is connected to the output of `stuff` (because pipes are files, just like nearly everything else in unix).

There is no quoting going on in the sense that a lisp programmer would use the word.

Comment: Yeah, indeed I was thinking about Lisp :-)